# Replace a request with a scheduled job and use the Response to update an endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am a newbie on this so my question looks a bit more simple.
i am working on a logic app where the steps are like:

1. Run the logic app on a scheduled trigger to get a list of orders that have a specific status (e.g. not processed) from an endpoint (endpoint1).
2. Process each orderNumber and send a request to another endpoint (endpoint2) to retrieve the status of each order number.
3. Get that status and send it back to endpoint1 along with the orderNumber with an updated status (endpoint1 Update method with the orderNumber and orderStatus)

[image]

**Problem:**

1. I can do step 1 by doing "When a HTTP request is received" but need to know how can I run a scheduled job to get a list of orderNumbers and then pass them in For-Each loop.
2. In For-Each, I am sending a request against each orderNumber and getting the response, but don't know how can I use that response to update the orderNumber with the new status in endpoint1.

Appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

Comment: Hi @sam, have you checked my answer? If it answers your question, kindly mark it as the answer so this question can be closed.

Comment: I am so sorry, will do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For scheduled workflows, choose the "Recurrence" trigger.
   [image]
2. In the For-Each loop, with the assumption that the response of your first http request is in JSON format, you will first need a "[Parse Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" step. In 'Content' you should have the response from your http step. Then use a sample response payload to generate the response schema. Once this is done, you can use another http request to fire the next API call. You should be able to use the response fields from the first API call to make the next call.
   [image]